# how can the whole NSMutableArray be filled with the same object(NSString)

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsmutablearray

I'm trying this, but it looks like it's not right, are there any options? Thank you

```
NSMutableArray *copyy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
for (int i = 1; i < copyy.count; i++) {
    NSString *str = @"test";
    [copyy addObject:[str copy][i]];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an NSArray initialized with count N, all of the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071648/creating-an-nsarray-initialized-with-count-n-all-of-the-same-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple category on top of the `NSArray` like:

```
@interface NSArray(Repeating)
+ (NSArray*)arrayByRepeatingObject:(id)object times:(NSUInteger)t;
@end

@implementation NSArray(Repeating)
+ (NSArray*)arrayByRepeatingObject:(id)object times:(NSUInteger)t {
    id objects[t];
    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<t; ++i) objects[i] = object;
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objects count:t];
}
@end
```

so you can build an array by repeating an object like:

```
NSArray * items = [NSArray arrayByRepeatingObject:@"test" times:8];
```

**Note:** if you want a mutable version, just ask for a `mutableCopy`:

```
NSMutableArray * mutableItems = items.mutableCopy;
```

Comment: ty for the quick response, sir. that's what I need.